# Save XDocument issue

Tags: silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm loading my document like so:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("Rolls.xml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then on the Read Completed:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(e.Result));

       using (Stream stream = e.Result)
       {
           {
               foreach (var roll in _rollsToAddStudentTo)
               {
                   doc.Element("rolls").Add(new XElement("rollid", roll));
               }
               doc.Save(stream);
           }

       }
```

The problem is when it gets to the save I get the error

> "Specified method is not supported."

Help will be much appreciated.
Cheers

Thanks Jehof,

So, how would I incorporate my document into that async method?

```
foreach (var roll in _rollsToAddStudentTo)
               {
                   doc.Element("rolls").Add(new XElement("rollid", roll));
               }

               WebClient client = new WebClient();
               client.OpenWriteCompleted += new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenWriteCompleted);
               client.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri("Rolls.xml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I have resolved this by changing my logic to below.

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore =
           IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                // Create new file
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
                    new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Rolls.xml",
                        FileMode.Create, isoStore))
                {
                    // Write to the Isolated Storage for the user.
                    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.Indent = true;
                    // Create an XmlWriter.
                    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(isoStream, settings))
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartDocument();
                        writer.WriteStartElement("Rolls");

                        foreach (var roll in _rollsToAddStudentTo)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement("roll");
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("rollid", roll);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }

                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndDocument();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The stream you try to save the XDocument is `readonly`. Cause it is the stream you get passed as argument to your method `client_OpenReadCompleted` that is registered to the event `OpenReadCompleted`.

If you want to save your XDocument back via WebClient you need to call one of the [OpenWriteAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwriteasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)-methods.